# View organization permissions

Tags: github

As an administrator, you can [**set permission levels**](http://github.com/blog/674-introducing-organizations) for members, for example

```
Pull Only
Push & Pull
Push, Pull & Administrative
```

However as a **member**, how can you tell what your permissions are other than testing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once logged in, switch account context to the organization

> [image: context]

Choose <kbd>**Teams**</kbd> tab. Under this tab you will find the permissions for each team.